# How to convert datetime to ISO 8601 format

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a date value in a field in XML file in this format:

```
<date>2017-05-01 00:00:00</date>
```

I want to convert it into a standard XSD format:

```
2017-05-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

I'm currently using version 3.0.

My stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
version="3.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="theDate" select="/item/date" />

<xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <Bundle>
        <thedate>
            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="$theDate"/></xsl:attribute>
        </thedate>
    </Bundle>
</xsl:template>
```

XML input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
    <date>2017-05-01 00:00:00</date> 
</item>
```

Would like output to look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bundle xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <thedate value="2017-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"/>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: What you have is a *string*, not a date or datetime. Simply translate the space to a `T` and add a `Z` and you're done.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  translate did the magic.  <xsl:value-of select="translate($theDate,' ', 'T')"/>.000Z

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($theDate,' ', 'T')"/>+000Z
```

Comment: Your result is not a valid ISO 8601 datetime. You need to add either `Z` or `+00:00` - not `+000Z`.

Comment: it's how you get the result not the actual value where it can be hardcoded